# Database file size from sys.master_files and sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats are different

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Im using query to find out database file size. I'm using system view and DMV, because i do want to find out both- actual file size and theoretical (in case of [sparse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175823%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) files) file size.

```
Select 
    DB_NAME(mf.database_id) AS [Database Name], 
    mf.Name,  
    mf.physical_name PhysicalName,
    cast(mf.size as bigint) * 8192 mfSize_bytes, 
    fs.size_on_disk_bytes fsSize_bytes
From sys.master_files mf
    Left Join sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(DEFAULT, DEFAULT) fs 
        On mf.database_id = fs.database_id and mf.file_id = fs.file_id
Order By DB_NAME(mf.database_id)
```

I am confused- converted both values to "bytes", comparing them. But on all instances i checked- temdb file size (from sys.master_files) is **smaller** than file size on disk (from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats).

In all other cases if there is difference, then that is correct (size on disk is actually smaller than file size- because they are sparse files).

**What is the reason for this difference?**

UPDATE:
When i am querying

```
Select is_sparse, * From sys.database_files
```

On SQL Server 2005 database snapshot, then column is_sparse = 0 (because it is showing properties of the files from original database, not snapshot file. So- is there bug in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175823%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)?).

Comment: On my instances the size is the same for tempdb on some, and different on others. Actually only the log file is different, and it is larger in `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` - which seems opposite to what you are seeing. I believe the latter if we're talking about actual size on disk rather than space used within the file.

Comment: @AaronBertrand sorry, there was mistake- it had to be "smaller", just like in your case (mistake corrected in question).

Comment: On more than one instance, one of them SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are runing query on snapshot?

Comment: No, I'm running your query, which looks at `sys.master_files`. You should be using a non-database-specific catalog view for this, because the one in the snapshot is *actually* the view in the source database (that view doesn't actually exist in the snapshot, right?). This is kind of the whole point of a snapshot, it only contains the snapshot image of things that have changed, but they will always be pre-change, so even if you change properties of the source database file (there aren't many you can make while a snapshot exists), the snapshot will always say `is_sparse = 0`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that sounds very logical and completely right, thanks :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just from looking at the query results on my local development instance, there are two differences that I see (there are probably more):

1. `sys.master_files` returns the "virtual" size of a file, while `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` returns the on-disk size of the file. I only see different sizes for database snapshots, which use NTFS sparse files behind the scenes (and I did verify the allocated and on-disk sizes in Windows).
2. `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` does not return sizes for databases that are offline, while `sys.master_files` does.

For the case of `tempdb`, `sys.master_files` contains the *startup* file sizes for `tempdb`. If you investigate `sys.database_files` in the context of `tempdb`, you'll see the current sizes.

Comment: Seems you are right about "startup" size. But how do you know that? i cant see reference about that in documentation..

Comment: @Jānis: I basically went and discovered it when I noticed that the size of `tempdb` reported in Management Studio didn't match up with what was in `sys.master_files`. I have no idea if it is or isn't documented anywhere, but I totally agree that it should be documented if it isn't.